# code behind field validation only if value is selected in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, validation

I'm not an asp.net guru, so I'm facing bad times with this silly matter.
I have a registration form where a field (VAT NUMBER called 'piva') must be validate only if from a dropdown list the value "IT" has been selected.

This is the front code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="pivaTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("piva") %>' 
MaxLength="50" Width="400px" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredPiva" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="pivaTextBox" 
ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource, CampoObbligatorio %>" Display="Dynamic" 
CssClass="little_text" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="PivaEsistente" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Partita IVA esistente nel database" meta:resourcekey="PivaEsistente" 
ControlToValidate="pivaTextBox" CssClass="little_text" Display="Dynamic" 
onservervalidate="PIVAEsistente_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PivaSize" runat="server" ControlToValidate="pivaTextBox" CssClass="little_text" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Check the VAT Number length. 11 characters and only numbers."  ValidationExpression="[0-9]{11}"  ValidationGroup="pivaItalia">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

In the code behind I wrote this:

```
protected void PIVAEsistente_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string piva = args.Value;
    using (CMALinqModelDataContext ent = new CMALinqModelDataContext())
    {
        var n = (from u in ent.VUser
                 where u.piva == piva
                 select u).Count<VUser>();
        args.IsValid = n.ToString().Equals("0");
    }
}

protected void nazioneDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    DropDownList ddlProv = (DropDownList)FormUser.FindControl("provinciaDropDownList");


    if ("it".Equals(ddl.SelectedValue))
    {
        ddlProv.Enabled = true;
        Page.Validate("pivaItalia");

    }
    else
    {
        ddlProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ddlProv.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

the first method checks if a VAT number already exists and it works.
The second one check if "it" has been selected from the nations dropdown list and unlock the provinces dropdownlist AND SHOULD validate the VAT number according the RegularExpressionValidator above.

The fact is that it is always validate, but worst even if I get the error message, the form can be submitted.
That's not good.

Anyone could suggest any solution? What am I missing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I have edited my answer. Ciao

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is casing.

In your question you state " I have a registration form where a field (VAT NUMBER called 'piva') must be validate only if from a dropdown list the value "IT" has been selected.", yet in your code you are comparing the lowercase value to the selected value in this code:

```
if ("it".Equals(ddl.SelectedValue))
{
    ddlProv.Enabled = true;
    Page.Validate("pivaItalia");

}
else
{
    ddlProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlProv.Enabled = false;
}
```

Instead force the values being compared to the same case (either `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()`), like this:

```
if ("it".Equals(ddl.SelectedValue.ToLower()))
{
    ddlProv.Enabled = true;
    Page.Validate("pivaItalia");

}
else
{
    ddlProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlProv.Enabled = false;
}
```

OR

```
if ("IT".Equals(ddl.SelectedValue.ToUpper()))
{
    ddlProv.Enabled = true;
    Page.Validate("pivaItalia");

}
else
{
    ddlProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlProv.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Karl, he needs the SelectedItem and not the SelectedValue.

Comment: Sorry Karl. As I have written few seconds ago to FeliceM, the capital letters was a typo. I cannot control the validation to being stopped unless "it" is selected. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @FeliceM - FeliceM, my select box ha options so formed: <option value="it">Italy</option>. Actually I need the value. Again, the part where I open the provinces dropdown list by selecting "it" from nations, is working fine. What is not working, is the validation. It must be executed ONLY when "it" is selected, but it executes ALWAYS. I'm getting mad :(

Comment: @Aptivus, thats strange. let me make a test and I will update the code in my answer

Comment: I have rolled back my answer, so what is the issue, it must be checking for lower case "it"?

Answer (score 0):

Beside capital letters that you have to sort out, if it is the case, the problem is the "SelectedValue" you shall use **"SelectetItem"**.

```
if (ddl.SelectedItem.Equals("it"))
{
    ddlProv.Enabled = true;
    Page.Validate("pivaItalia");

}
else
{
    ddlProv.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ddlProv.Enabled = false;
}
```

I tested with this on a comboBox(ddl) where I have: it, pippo, papa, etc.., and it works:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl.SelectedItem.Equals("it"))
        {
            label1.Text = "ok";
        }

        else 
        {
            label1.Text = "no";
        }

    }
```

So if you still have problems, please explain better what is happening, may be the problem is now somewhere else.

Comment: Hi,thaks FeliceM. The fact is that the capital letters was a mistyping here on stackoverflow. the value is always "it" (lowercase). The problem is the validation doesn't start ONLY when the selected item equals "it", but it is always active. How am I supposed to "freeze" the validation unless "it" has been selected?

Comment: sorry to bother you Felice, would you guide me in this matter? How can I "freeze" the validation unless "it" has been selected? Is there any trick to make the validation only in the **true** case of the if that you wrote? I am very confused. The community help would be highly appreciated. More: are you italian? I am

Comment: @Aptivus, I have no idea why your verification does not work. There must be something somewhere else that is interfering. However, my contact is in the profile but I do not know what else I can do for you. Yes I am Italian.